# Tkinter python crashes on new thread trying to log on main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

i have created a tkinter gui that does some time consuming operations when clicking on some buttons. There are 2 main problems in my case that i think cause tkinter to crash in an unconssistent way.

1) I want to log some output from the new threads into a scrolled text widget that runs on the main thread, which i Think is not a good idea. Right now i do that by having a TextHandler object send to the threads (see my code)

2) In order to avoid logging from the new thread to the main thread, i want to know when the thread is done and then log from the main thread into the text widget but how does the main loop knows, when the thread is created in the function called from the Button press?

```
class TextHandler(logging.Handler):

"""This class allows you to log to a Tkinter Text or ScrolledText widget"""

def __init__(self, text):
    # run the regular Handler __init__
    logging.Handler.__init__(self)
    # Store a reference to the Text it will log to
    self.text = text

def emit(self, record):
    msg = self.format(record)
    def append():

        self.text.configure(state='normal')

        self.text.insert(tkinter.END, msg + '\n')
        self.text.configure(state=DISABLED)
        # Autoscroll to the bottom
        self.text.yview(tkinter.END)
    # This is necessary because we can't modify the Text from other threads
    self.text.after(0, append)


class GUI(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, logger, st):
....initialize stuff...


def _startComputations(self):

    if (self._paths == ""):
        self._logger.warn("No drive paths found, please add a path")
    else:
        if (self._flexinput == ""):
            self._logger.warn(self._flexinput)
            self._logger.warn("No file path,continuing with standard KM estimation")

        self.myThread = StandardUsecases(self._paths, self._input, 
                                     self._logger, self._standard_choices,
                                     self._numberOfoccurences_usecases, 
                                     self._all_logs, self._unique_countries,
                                     self.bt, self.bt2, self.bt3,
                                     self._flexinput)
        self.myThread.start()


        self._all_jsons = self.myThread._original_json_list
        self._general_json = self.myThread._general_json_data_list


def _KM_Button(self):

    self._all_logs[:] = []
    self.bt = Button(self.frame6, text='1-Main Usecases', font = "Helvetica 11 bold italic",
                command = self._startComputations,relief = RAISED, bd= 6, bg = "pale green", fg = 'black')
    self.bt.pack(side =  LEFT)

def initGUI(self):

    self.parent.title("DC Statistics calculator")

    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)   
    self._Drive_Paths()
    self._Flexray_Path()
    #self._UserInput()
    self._KM_Button()
    self._countButton()
    self._exportButton()
    self._helpButton()

def main():

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x800+400+400")

st = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, state='disabled')
st.configure(font="Times 13")
st.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill='both',expand='yes')

text_handler = TextHandler(st)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(text_handler)

app = GUI(root, logger, st)
root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

So after pressing the button, the _startComputations function will be called, and there the thread will be created. I send the _logger object so that i can log to the ScrolledText widget while i am on the new thread. But most of the times i get crashes like "python.exe stopped working" or tcl_appendlimitedtoobj called with shared object.

In the case i do not want to log from the new thread, how can the main loop know if the new thread is done, since the new thread is created withid the function called after the button press?

Thank you

Comment: I assume that your code isn't a thread safe. It's because you passing your text widget alongside with instance of `TextHandler` to a separate thread. And some methods of `TextHandler` casts methods of your `text` widget (e.g. `emit`), whom need to be casted from main thread. It's hard to tell what you need to fix since your code ain't a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but there're more simplier options. You can even hijack (for time, when you need it) `stdout` for logging purposes and `print` directly to widget or file!

Comment: Can you explain the "hijack" part? Also, is there a way, the main thread to know when the new thread is done? Since as i see it, the tkinter mainloop doesnt "know" about the new thread, so i cannot call the is_alive() method anywhere besides the function the thread is created

Comment: Another idea: you can "commit" and "pull" your `emit`'s to/from a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) (it's not thread safe too) object. You can check it (also, same idea with checking `is_alive()` status of a threads if you stored them) in [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) "loop" (functions can reschedule themself thanks to this method). General [idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333334/stdout-to-tkinter-gui) ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43805139/6634373)) of "hijack" part - redirecting `stdout` stuff.

Comment: Could you make a small example with the commit and pull  and the Queue. But since you are saying that it is not thread safe, will that work?

Comment: Of course it will, some little examples are [here](https://pymotw.com/2/Queue/) and [there](https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics), and it's a common pattern in general! Also, on SO there are a lot of small but more specific examples. I bet, if you try to google it by "threading", "python", "queue" keywords, you'll find them all!

Comment: Is there a tkinter method that is being called so that i check if my queue if empty or not ? Now i have created a queue, that i fill in into my second thread. But where in the main thread can i check if the queue has something to output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in comments - your error occures because you passing your `text` widget alongside with instance of `TextHandler` to a separate thread. And some methods of `TextHandler` casts methods of your `text` widget (e.g. `emit`), whom need to be casted from main thread.

The simpliest solution to overcome your problem is a [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html) object. You can't cast `tkinter` methods (e.g. write something to a widget) from other threads, but you can populate a `queue`! The main idea here - continiously check a `queue` while anyone of a task's threads exists. To continiously check the `queue` we need an [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) "loop" and `list` of tasks:

```
def listen(self, force_start=False):
    #   "after" loop - listener
    self.listen_queue()

    if self.task_list or force_start:
        print('Listener: Listen')
        self.after(100, self.listen)
    else:
        print('Listener: Off')
```

Inside whom we trying to [pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247439/python-queue-empty-exception-handling) something from a `queue`:

```
def listen_queue(self):
    #   listen queue
    while self.log_queue.qsize():
        try:
            self.logger.warning(self.log_queue.get())
        except queue.Empty:
            pass
```

Of course you can start to listen a `queue` right from the start of your application and, in general, your loop would look like this:

```
def listen(self, force_start=False):
    #   "after" loop - listener
    self.listen_queue()
    self.after(100, self.listen)
```

But again, if you want more control over threads - `list` with them is a good idea! I think that now you got the pattern, so here's a complete example:

```
#   imports
try:
    import tkinter as tk              # Python 3
    import queue
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk              # Python 2
    import Queue as queue

import logging
import threading
import random
import string


#   classes
class TextHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, text):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        # Store a reference to the Text it will log to
        self.text = text

    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)

        self.text.configure(state='normal')
        self.text.insert(tk.END, msg + '\n')
        self.text.configure(state=tk.DISABLED)
        self.text.yview(tk.END)


class App(tk.Tk):
    #   common tk app
    def __init__(self):
        #   initiate root
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        #   initiate widgets
        self.spawn_task_button = tk.Button(self, text='Spawn Task', command=self.spawn_task)
        self.spawn_task_button.pack(expand=True, fill='x')

        self.quit_button = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.close_app)
        self.quit_button.pack(expand=True, fill='x')

        self.text_console = tk.Text(self, bg='black', fg='white')
        self.text_console.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        #   initiate queue, task list, logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logger.addHandler(TextHandler(self.text_console))

        self.log_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.task_list = []

        #   initiate events and protocols
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self.close_app)

    def put_line_to_queue(self, log_line=''):
        #   put log line to queue
        self.log_queue.put(log_line)

    def listen_queue(self):
        #   listen queue
        while self.log_queue.qsize():
            try:
                self.logger.warning(self.log_queue.get())
            except queue.Empty:
                pass

    def listen(self, force_start=False):
        #   "after" loop - listener
        self.listen_queue()

        if self.task_list or force_start:
            print('Listener: Listen')
            self.after(100, self.listen)
        else:
            print('Listener: Off')

    def common_task(self, task_thread):
        #   example task wait + print

        #   add task to task_list
        self.task_list.append(task_thread)

        iteration_count = random.randint(1, 10)
        task_numb = task_thread.name[-1:]

        self.put_line_to_queue('\n*** Task %s: Spawned \t Iteration count: %d ***\n' % (task_numb, iteration_count))

        for _ in range(iteration_count):
            threading.Event().wait(1)
            self.put_line_to_queue('Task %s: In Progress \t Iteration: %d \t Generated: %s' % (task_numb, _ + 1,
                                                                                                 generate_smth()))

        self.put_line_to_queue('Task %s: Completed\n' % task_numb)

        #   remove task from task_list
        self.task_list.remove(task_thread)

    def spawn_task(self):
        #   spawn another task
        task = threading.Thread(target=lambda: self.common_task(task))

        #   "kick start" listener if task list is empty
        if not self.task_list:
            self.listen(force_start=True)

        task.start()

    def close_app(self):
        # handle closing
        if self.task_list:
            #   code to handle threads
            #   there're some threads in a list
            self.put_line_to_queue('\n**** Cant quit right now! ****\n')
        else:
            self.destroy()


#   functions
def generate_smth(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    # generate random
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

#   entry point
app = App()
app.mainloop()
```