# why this Tensorflow code raises tf.errors.OutOfRangeError?

Tags: python, tensorflow, queue, outofrangeexception

This Tensorflow code below raises a `tf.errors.OutofRangeError`:

```
try:
     while not coord.should_stop():        
          vector1,vector2,vector3,vector4,vector5,labels = sess.run([train_vector1,train_vector2,train_vector3,train_vector4,train_vector5,train_labels])
          shape1 = tf.shape(vector1)
          print (sess.run(shape1))
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
   print ('tf.errors.OutOfRangeError')

finally:
    coord.request_stop()
```

Why is `tf.errors.OutofRangeError` printed when all the samples are read?
It seems unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

From [tf.errors.OutofRangeError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/errors/OutOfRangeError) doc:

> Raised when an operation iterates past the valid input range.
>
> This exception is raised in "end-of-file" conditions, such as when a
>   `tf.QueueBase.dequeue` operation is blocked on an empty queue, and a
>   `tf.QueueBase.close` operation executes.

I.e. it is a normal, python-esque behavior. You are iterating over your queue until it's empty; and you know it is when the `OutofRangeError` is thrown.

This also matches the behavior of normal python `Queue`:

```python
import Queue

q = Queue.Queue()
try:
    task=q.get(False)
    # ...
except Queue.Empty:
    # Handle empty queue here
    pass
```

You can find a small discussion here on the advantages of this try-catch concept: [Python: Queue.Empty Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247439/python-queue-empty-exception-handling).